# Python-compute the histogram of a set of data

Tags: python, histogram

The Python function below is to compute histogram of data, with equal-sized bins. I would like to get the correct result

```
[1, 6, 4, 6]
```

However after I run the code, it get result

```
[7, 12, 17, 17]
```

which is not correct. Can anybody know how to fix it?

```
# Computes the histogram of a set of data
def histogram(data, num_bins):

# Find what range the data spans, and use it to calculate the bin size.
span = max(data) - min(data)
bin_size = span / num_bins

# Calculate the thresholds for each bin.
thresholds = [0] * num_bins
for i in range(num_bins):
    thresholds[i] += bin_size * (i+1)

# Compute the histogram
counts = [0] * num_bins
for datum in data:
    # Increment the count of the bin that the datum falls in
    for bin_index, threshold in enumerate(thresholds):
        if datum <= threshold:
            counts[bin_index] += 1
return counts

# Some random data
data = [-3.2, 0, 1, 1.5, 1.6, 1.9, 5, 6, 9, 1, 4, 5, 8, 9, 5, 6.7, 9]
print("Correct result:\t" + str([1, 6, 4, 6]))
print("Your result:\t" + str(histogram(data, num_bins=4)))
```

Comment: What do you think is making it incorrect?

Comment: Your code is not valid Python. Please [edit] it and fix the indention.

Comment: @Donkey Kong: I would like to get the correct result [1, 6, 4, 6]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only you have two logical errors

(1) calculating the threshold

(2) add break in for, once found the range

```
def histogram(data, num_bins):
  span = max(data) - min(data)
  bin_size = float(span) / num_bins
  thresholds = [0] * num_bins

  for i in range(num_bins):
    #I change thresholds calc
    thresholds[i] = min(data) + bin_size * (i+1)

  counts = [0] * num_bins
  for datum in data:
    for bin_index, threshold in enumerate(thresholds):
      if datum <= threshold:
        counts[bin_index] += 1
        #I add a break
        break
  return counts

data = [-3.2, 0, 1, 1.5, 1.6, 1.9, 5, 6, 9, 1, 4, 5, 8, 9, 5, 6.7, 9]
print("Correct result:\t" + str([1, 6, 4, 6]))
print("Your result:\t" + str(histogram(data, num_bins=4)))
```

Answer (score 5):

if you want to find the histogram use numpy

```
import numpy as np
np.histogram([-3.2, 0, 1, 1.5, 1.6, 1.9, 5, 6, 9, 1, 4, 5, 8, 9, 5, 6.7, 9],4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check threshold definition and if statement.
this works:

```
def histogram(data, num_bins):

    # Find what range the data spans, and use it to calculate the bin size.
    span = max(data) - min(data)
    bin_size = span / float(num_bins)

    # Calculate the thresholds for each bin.
    thresholds = [0 for i in range(num_bins+1)]
    for i in range(num_bins):
        thresholds[i] += bin_size * (i)

    print thresholds
    # Compute the histogram
    counts = [0 for i in range(num_bins)]
    for datum in data:
        # Increment the count of the bin that the datum falls in
        for bin_index, threshold in enumerate(thresholds):
            if thresholds[bin_index-1] <= datum <= threshold:
                counts[bin_index] += 1
    return counts
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if just want to histogram your data, numpy provides this. However, you ask how to do this yourself.  You code suggests you lost track of what you were trying to do, so break up your function into smaller functions.  For example, to compute the thresholds, write a function `thresholds(xmin, xmax, nbins)`, or better yet use `numpy.linspace`.  This will draw your attention to the problem that arises if you assume you are incrementing relative to `0` (instead of to `min(data)`) and, if you are lucky, may remind you not to hope for exact floating point accumulations. So you might end up with

```
def thresholds(xmin, xmax, nbins):
    span = (xmax - xmin) / float(nbins)
    thresholds = [xmin + (i+1)*span for i in range(nbins)]
    thresholds[-1] = xmax
    return thresholds
```

Next, you need to get the bin counts.  Again, you could just use `numpy.digitize`.  The important thing, in contrast to your code, is not to increment more than one bin. In the end you might get something like

```
def counts(data, bounds):
    counts = [0] * len(bounds)
    for datum in data:
        bin = min(i for i,bound in enumerate(bounds) if bound >= datum)
        counts[bin] += 1
    return counts
```

Now you're ready to go:

```
def histogram02(data, num_bins):
    xmin = min(data)
    xmax = max(data)
    th = thresholds(xmin, xmax, num_bins)
    return counts(data, th)
```